# "Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Tags: c#, token

I get the error "Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" in my following C # code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static int a, b;
        void add(int x, int y);
        {
            int c= x+y;
            Console.WriteLine("addition is " + char);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   

        }
   }
}
```

Your help in solving will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Anees

Answer (score 6):

There is error because you have semicolon in there and there is wrong variable name, fix:

```
void add(int x, int y)
{
    int c= x+y;
    Console.WriteLine("addition is " + c);
}
```

Comment: Great help......Thank you so much.... it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon after your method declaration `void add(int x, int y);`. Change it to

```
void add(int x, int y)
```

and What is `char` inside `Console.WriteLine("addition is " + char)`? Change `char` to `c`.

```
Console.WriteLine("addition is " + c);
```

No need to write `c.ToString()` because when an entity is appended with string it automatically calls its `ToString()` method. (Coz this method is available to all entities of .Net).

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon after this method declaration and change char to c in Console.Writeline

```
void add(int x, int y);
{
        int c= x+y;
        Console.WriteLine("addition is " + char);
    }
```

Instead write

```
 void add(int x, int y)
{
        int c= x+y;
        Console.WriteLine("addition is " + c);
    }
```

Comment: This is simply UNBELIEVABLE!!! I had tons of ridiculous errors and only after I read this comment and searched for mysterious semi-colons, I found one and it cleared ALL of my errors! YOU SAVED ME! and VisualStudio COULD handle it better...:)